# What does METAR show when actual RVR is below the reporting minimum?

Tags: metar, visibility

RVR is measured between 50m and 1500m (ICAO). When the actual RVR is below 50m, what does METAR show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - If the RVR is less than the minimum value that can be measured , M will precede this value e.g. R24L/M0050.

If measured in ft, then FT will follow. For example: R24L/**M0200FT**

For greater than can be measured and trends:

> - If the RVR is greater than the maximum value that can be measured, P will precede this value e.g. R24L/P1500.
> - If RVR trends can be measured then U, D, or N will follow the RVR value to indicate increasing, decreasing or no change respectively.

---

Source: https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Meteorological_Terminal_Air_Report_(METAR)